# How to set a home page for users based on roles?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created a page-view 'dashboard' and 'member-view'. I want 'dashboard' page as home page for librarian and 'member-view' as home page for member. How can I do it? Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could use the [rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to do a redirect depending on role

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a module available for redirecting users based on roles.
https://www.drupal.org/project/login_destination

Comment: But that is only on login, it does not actually change the homepage ..

Answer (score 2):

I added a basic page with the following code and made the basic page my default front page. Thus I could route the users based on roles.

```
if($user->uid) {
    if(!empty($user->roles)) {
        if (in_array('Librarian', $user->roles, true)) {
            drupal_goto("dashboard");
        }
        elseif (in_array('administrator', $user->roles, true)) {
            drupal_goto("dashboard");
        }
        elseif (in_array('Member', $user->roles, true)) {
            drupal_goto("member-view");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You must enable the php filter module for writing the code in the basic page and select the text format to PHP code.